# Listbox with gridsplitter resize itself instead of showing a scrollbar

Tags: wpf, listbox, grid, resize, gridsplitter

In my application I need to have a listbox to display at the bottom of the screen.  The listbox can be displayed of not (via a menu entry), and must be resizable in height.  I placed it in a grid and used a gridsplitter to do the resize part, which works as intended.

My problem is, if no manual resize before, once log begins to appear in the listbox, this listbox does not show a scrollbar but instead in begins growing and takes more space.  Once I trigger a resize using the gridsplitter, everything works as intended.  What can I do to stop this ?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                  Height="5"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Visibility="{Binding ShowLogWindow,
                                       Converter={StaticResource Bool2Vis}}" />

    <ListBox Grid.Row="2"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Toolbox.LogEntries}"
             MinHeight="50"
             Visibility="{Binding ShowLogWindow,
                                  Converter={StaticResource Bool2Vis}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Don't set `Height="Auto"` on the third row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Height` of the third `RowDefinition` (or the `ListBox` itself) to 50 or whatever fixed height you want it to have.

`Auto` means size to content, which means that the height of the last row will grow as the `ListBox` grows. This is not what you want apparently.

Comment: That completely did it !  I tought setting the height there would prevent the resizing... Should have tried it..  Thanks!

Comment: Just to add information, I had to use a style (and a trigger) to set the height of the row so I can hide it colpmetely when needed.